# In HTML5 Video , how to play a small clip from a long video?

Tags: html, html5-video

I would like to show a small clip from a long video  file that is over 10 minutes long.  This  segment  of video  would start at time offset /seek time of 90 seconds and would have a duration  of 45 seconds . How can I do that  ?

Comment: Be aware that this way you will be transferring the whole video (which might be rather big in terms of filesize) to your client's device. A user-friendly approach would probably solve this in editing already and supply a specific file that only covers the snippet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Phillip Brown is right. you can solve this by controlling yout html-player via js. for example in this case, the video would autostart and will play the videofile should 00:10min to 00:40min

```
<video id="yourVideoplayer" width="640" height="480" preload="auto"> //preload="auto" buffers the video if initialize. you cannot seek a video which isn t buffering already
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="test.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> 
  This browser is not compatible with HTML 5
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = playVideoTeaserFrom(10,40);   //this event will call the function after page was loaded

   function playVideoTeaserFrom (startTime, endTime) {
       var videoplayer = document.getElementById("yourVideoplayer");  //get your videoplayer

       videoplayer.currentTime = starttime; //not sure if player seeks to seconds or milliseconds
       videoplayer.play();

       //call function to stop player after given intervall
       var stopVideoAfter = (endTime - startTime) * 1000;  //* 1000, because Timer is in ms
       setTimeout(function(){
           videoplayer.stop();
       }, stopVideoAfter);

   }
 </script>
```

there might be some bugs in it, but i guess you ll get the point

Comment: This function doesn't seem to work. Video is normally running full length.

Comment: That's because @longilong set `window.onload` to undefined, and other problems with the code. There are obvious bugs.

Comment: If the user fast forwards or rewinds with the mouse the timer would stop at a certain time different from the one expect it to.

Comment: This is a bad solution - if the user interacts with the video (pause for example) it will completely distort the TO calculation. 

to solve this issue you should listen to `timeupdate` event, and pause the video if `vid.currentTime` is not between start to end

Comment: Jim S answer should be marked as correct as it's part of the spec, but I think this answer is a great way to demonstrate programmatic access, so hat off to you!

Answer (score 54):

HTML5 video also supports the [Media Fragment URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/) spec. This will allow you to specify only a segment of the video to play. Using it is fairly trivial:

```
<source src="video.mp4#t=30,45" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Will start the video at the 30 second mark and pause the video at the 45 second mark.

Comment: Just a note that I noticed that Chrome continues to download the rest of the video.  It pauses the video at 45 seconds, but a user can resume play from that point.  If you're looking at this as a means to limit traffic or to cut off the rest of a video, this is not your solution.

Comment: You'll need to work with the video player controls to prevent this. You could make the video player jump back to 30 seconds into the video if the play button is pressed when the video is at the 45 second mark. It would be pretty trivial to parse the media fragments out of the src to make that kind of functionality.

Comment: If this is widely supported in all major browsers then it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Browser support should not matter. This is part of a w3c spec that is approved, then it should be the top answer for technical merit. However the JS answer (also depends on browser implementation of DOM & JS); is a great way to show programmatic access to media via HTML5

Comment: Is it possible to have two different segments? so that it plays one and then the other?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<video id="myVideo"  controls playsinline muted>
    <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_30mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
  
  let vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms));

  async function run(start,end,speed=1){
    vid.playbackRate = speed
    while(true){
        vid.currentTime = start;
        await vid.play()
        await delay((end - start)*1000)
        
        await vid.pause()
    }
  }
  window.onload = run(70,74)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

We can use asynchronies function to achieve this. This code is a modified version of  @longi code