# Play subclip of video

Tags: video, jwplayer, clip

Here is my very basic page that plays a video with jwplayer:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id='my-video'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('my-video').setup({
    'file': 'video.m3u8',
    'width': '640',
    'height': '360'
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The video is a 2 hour video and I would like to play just a segment of it (for example have the video start at 5 minutes and end at 10 minutes). In another area of the website I am going to play a different segment of the same video, so I would like to keep the same file and not alter it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Yeah, a link would be helpful here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In HTML5 Video , how to play a small clip from a long video?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845565/in-html5-video-how-to-play-a-small-clip-from-a-long-video)