# Trim the beginning of a video Blob (webm) in javascript

Tags: javascript, webm

I have a video Blob array in Javascript; the array is segmented into 1 second intervals.  I want to trim from the beginning and end of the video.

I found this post ([how-to-edit-trim-a-video-in-the-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806571/how-to-edit-trim-a-video-in-the-browser)) describing how to trim my blob, but it only works for the end of the video.

I suspect that removing the beginning of the blob removes the header information and makes the webm invalid.

This works:
`// remove 2 seconds from the end of the video
const trimmedVideo = blobArray.slice(0, blobArray.length - 2);`

This does not work:
`// remove 1 second from the start of the video
const trimmedVideo = blobArray.slice(1, blobArray.length);`

How can I trim from the beginning of my video blob?

Comment: It would also be nice to have a solution which can trim precisely. Even setting the chunks size to 1 seconds doesn't guarantee they will be exactly that.

Comment: @jj. Are you able to solve this?

Comment: Hi @rbansal - this was for a (javascript) chromeos app, so I was able to solve it by incorporating ffmpeg into the app build. It was many years ago now, so maybe there is a js-only solution that exists that did not back then?

Answer (score 0):

A hacky and sub-optimal solution, you could set your blob as the source of a video element, then seek to the timestamp where you want to start trimming (could even do this through the uri using `#t=[starttime][,endtime]` syntax), stream that video element to a new recorder, and play it until the timestamp you want to trim.

You can simplify this a bit by trimming the end by discarding blob chunks, but as @Nuthinking said, you'd lose precision (even the video player won't be 100% precise though, I believe firefox works with 2ms precision).

While I believe this would work, and the video doesn't need to be in the DOM, you'd be encoding at 1:1 time.

I'm not aware of any other answers to this that would involve just HTML5. This question is tricky because the `MediaRecorder` API explicitly says blob chunks produced need not be playable by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The `mediarecorder` object that the original solution uses has a method called `requestData()`, which apparently continues recording in a new Blob after it is called.

Maybe you can use this to continue to record in a new Blob after you find the start point of your edited footage.