# Local / session storage - pause video and playback from where it has stoped - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, html5-video, session-storage

I know this question is possible duplicate. SO has suggested lot links me when typing my question side by side.

my situation is, 
**example:** i've 3 videos as course for each user which are visible only after logged in. the thing is i just want play the video where it has paused.

**example** Video_001 has length 4 mins. but user has watched till 2.30 mins and did the same for Video_002 and then logged out. if user logged in again. the videos has to start from where it has stopped.

pls see this

```
`https://codepen.io/theNoobsCode/pen/omgGZx`
```

could someone tell me where and how to use local/session storage here and what needs to be change?

kindly share your thoughts and examples if possible
helps much appreciated.

Comment: Split your problem in multiple smaller tasks. You need 1. get an event when user logs out. 2. get video's current time when this event fires. 3. store this time info in Storage. 4. retrieve this info from Storage at next login. 5. set the video's current time to a fixed value (the one that has been stored). All these 5 questions have been asked many time in here, and should not be too hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can save the fragment end time from where it is paused in local storage.
2. When user comes back you can get the fragment end time from local storage of that video and pass to following code

   e.g. user has watched video for 40 seconds and if you want start video again after 40 seconds you can use following

> ```
> <source src="video.mp4#t=40,100" type="video/mp4"/>
> ```

[For more details you can see following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845565/in-html5-video-how-to-play-a-small-clip-from-a-long-video)